# Android - Network State broadcast receiver does not receive intent

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have a broadcast receiver that needs to listen to network changes -

```
BroadcastReceiver networkStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean noConnectivity =
            intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        if(!noConnectivity)
        {
            //some stuff
        }
    }
};
```

I register it using -

```
public void startListening() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        context.registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, filter);
}
```

I have added the following permission in the manifest -

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

The networkStateReceiver still does not receive any intent when I switch the phone to airplane mode, switch wifi off etc. Am I missing something?

Comment: I experimented the same issue... Did you fix??

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can able to use this:

At first add this before @Override

```
private boolean isConnected = true;
private Context c;
```

Then use it

```
//check for connectivity:
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo TestConnetion = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (TestConnetion == null){
isConnected=false;  
}
```

Comment: Why does this answer the question? How does this help in getting the intent sent to the receiver?

Answer (score 4):

Try using this action instead:

`Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED`

**Edit**

Or for all network state changes, use:

`"android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE"`