# how to call a section of code every second in background in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want call the following portion of code every second??
I have tried the following-
But don't know how to call every second??

How can I keep on calling      **new checkNWConnectivity().execute("Test");**    everysecond    and from where to call   in my android program???

```
private class checkNWConnectivity extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


                ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(MainActivity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                //  3G confirm
                Boolean is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnectedOrConnecting();

                // wifi confirm 
                Boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();

                if(is3g){
                    tvNWConnectivity.setText("   Connected to 3G");
                }else if(isWifi){
                    tvNWConnectivity.setText("   Connected to wifi");
                }else{
                    String text = "   No Network Connectivity."+"\n" + "   Uploading will be resumed from streamlet "+countStreamletUploaded.toString();
                    tvNWConnectivity.setText(text);
                 }    


        return null;
    }

}
```

**So my question is** how to call it every second?
**Actually I want to keep on running the portion of code in doInBackground(String... params) { ... }**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html), [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to do this:

```
 public void toCallAsynchronous() {

   TimerTask doAsynchronousTask;
   final Handler handler = new Handler();
   Timer timer = new Timer();

   doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                          checkNWConnectivity performBackgroundTask = new checkNWConnectivity();
                          performBackgroundTask.execute();

                           } catch (Exception e) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                           }

                     }
                });
                timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0,30000); //put the time you want

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Parth.
It's working.
But when I am starting another job in background then this stop working   and when that job completed then It again start working.
I want to let this background job keep on working.
How is this possible?
Can we not run two background job together, may be via different thread??

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible  ..Hope it helps to solve your query

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a ScheduledExecutorService

```
ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(command, initialDelay, period, unit);
```

Create the executor OnCreate of your activity, start the execution onResume and stop it onPause.

then you can call `runOnUiThread(action);` to post actions back to the UI.

Answer (score 1):

1. From your code, it looks like you are trying to show the network state. It is not a good idea to poll for the information. It is better to use a BroadcastReceiver to listen for changes in network state. Check these question: [Android - Network State broadcast receiver does not receive intent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6615245/1321873), [Broadcast Intent when network state has changend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2676044/1321873)
2. If you have to perform periodic operations, you could use a [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

Answer (score 0):

At first you can't work with views from non-UI thread so you can't call `TextView.setText` from `AsyncTask.doInBackground` method. You can simply use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and submit a message every second using `Handler.sendMessageDelayed`

Answer (score 0):

the way I did this was to put the thread in a Service

the service would do a countdown timer from a very large number, so it would never get to zero, but that was just a use case for my app, you might need something that goes forever

then there is the dilemma of manipulating the UI thread. My loop in the Service would edit a variable in SharedPreferences and my Activity had a loop checked SharedPreferences and would update UI objects if SharedPreferences returned a certain value, problem solved.

You may be able to do something similar with broadcast receivers

Answer (score 0):

Use Handler.

```
    private class MyHandler extends Handler{
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message){

            YourAsyncTask task = new YourAsyncTask(...);
            task.execute();
                    this.sendMessageDelayed(new Message(), 1000);}
}
```

Then when you want to start just do this

```
MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
handler.sendMessageDelayed(new Message(), 1000);
```